# PyCharm: Unresolved attribute reference for class MyClass - Initialization of variables as instance-level variables

Tags: python, pycharm, prometheus

I have code where I want to initialize prometheus variables to get some metrics.

```
from prometheus_client import Counter, Gauge, Histogram
import time

class MyClass:

        def __init__(self):
               self.number_of_clicks: Optional[Counter]
               self.number_of_items: Optional[Gauge]
               self.prometheus_processing_time: Optional[Histogram]

        def do_something:
               number_of_clicks = ...
               number_of_items = ...
               elapsed_time = time.time_ns() - start_time
               self.number_of_clicks.inc(amount=number_of_clicks)
               self.number_of_items.inc(amount=number_of_items)
               self.prometheus_processing_time.inc(amount=elapsed_time)
```

I now get the yellow warning: Unresolved attribute reference "number_of_clicks" for class "MyClass". I am wondering if I should initialize the metrics somehwo else, e.g.: `self.number_of_clicks: Optional[Counter] = Counter()`? Can someone help me and explain this warning?

Comment: You should initialize all instance attributes in the `__init__()` method. That's how PyCharm knows which attributes are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Thank you! That means I could initialize it likse this: `self.number_of_clicks: Optional[Counter] = None`?

Comment: If the value is optional you can set `self.number_of_clicks: Optional[Counter] = None`. That's perfectly fine. But how can this value be optional when you call `self.number_of_clicks.inc` later?

Comment: It shouldn't be optional, since `inc()` doesn't work when it's not set.

Comment: Ok, then it should be something like this?
`self.number_of_clicks: Counter = Counter('name', 'documentation')`?